# Factorial program using recurrsion returning wrong value

Tags: c, recursion, factorial

I am trying to calculate factorial using recursion  but my program is returning wrong value. I am unable to understand the recursion functionality. Please help me in understanding how recursion works. My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() 
{
    //code
    int T,N,sol;
    scanf("%d\n",&T);

    while(T--) {
        scanf("%d\n",&N);

        sol=fact(N);
        printf("%d\n",sol);
    }

    return 0;
}

int fact(int n)
{
    int value;
    while(n>0) {
        value=n*fact(n-1);
        n=n-1;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Because you've set up the function incorrectly

Comment: initialize `value` before using it. Plus the function is wrong too.

Comment: @AndrewL. can you please let me know where is the error in the function

Comment: When `n == 0`, what is the value you return?

Comment: When using recursion, set up a terminatory case, or base case in which recursion ends. Then set up a general case for recursion to continue, with different parameter values.

Comment: The loop is weird, too.  Either iterate or recurse, but don't do both.

Comment: Your compiler should also have shouted on you because you are using the `fact` function before it is declared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your fact function with this one:

```
int fact(int n)
{
    int value = 1;
    if(n>0)
    {
        value=n*fact(n-1);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: This is a correct answer, but please explain the reasoning, don't just post code

Answer (score 0):

You are using recursion as well as a while loop in the function `fact`

A recursion should replace the loop. You also need an exit condition for the function. For the factorial it can be at `0` and the factorial of `0` is  `1`.

The function can be rewritten as below

```
int fact(int n)
{
  int value;
  if (n <0)
  {
     return -1;
  }
  else if (n == 0)
  { 
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    value=n*fact(n-1);
  }
  return value;
}
```

Edited to add condition for negative numbers. If the function returns -1, then the main program should give the user an error message.

Comment: If you pass a negative value, the recursion will never end.

Comment: Factorial for a negative number is not defined. If we expect a negative number, then some other sort of error should be given, preferably at input stage, The function can also return -1 to indicate error.

Comment: So then set up a case for that